# Apple Watch Motion face: is there any way to just pick one flower as the default flower?

Tags: watchos, apple-watch

Is there any way to just pick one flower as the default flower?

Answer (score 1):

As of watchOS 4 (and the newest watchOS 5 beta), you can't really do that, Apple didn't make it possible.